# C ++ How to call ifstream with void?

Tags: c++, struct, void

In summary:

1 - structure with variables

2 - assign values ​​to variables

3 - void save variables in file

4 - change values ​​to variables

5 - void load values ​​into variables <--- Here I have the problem

6 - I show the values

My problem is this: I am creating a system for saving and loading "games" in C ++ with codeblocks. A simple code was used to create the system in question, but also for the value of the variables housed in a structure (almost all int) in a .txt or a .dat.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

///GAME VAR
struct NewGame{
float tipo;
float health;
};

///SAVE_LOAD
void saveGame( NewGame G );
void loadGame( NewGame ( & G ) );

int main(){

///STRUCT
NewGame G;

///VALUE ASIGN (TEST)
cout << "Ingrese tipo [1] [2] [3]" << endl;
cin >> G.tipo;
cout << "Ingrese vida"<<endl;
cin >> G.health;

///SAVE STRUCT
    saveGame( G );

///CHANGE VALUES
G.health = 0;
G.tipo = 0;

///LOAD STRUCT <-----HERE'S THE PROBLEM
    loadGame( G );

///TEST VALUES
cout << "HEALTH: " << G.health << endl;
cout << "TYPE: " << G.tipo << endl;


return 0;
}

///SAVE
void saveGame( NewGame G){

ofstream s;
    s.open("save.txt");
    s << G.health << endl;
    s << G.tipo << endl;
    s.close();

};

///LOAD
void loadGame( NewGame ( & G ) ){

ifstream l;
    l.open("save.txt");
    l >> G.health;
    l >> G.tipo;
    l.close();

};
```

I have already tried several methods, in binary and txt the problem is always the same, the data is saved, the values ​​are tested after loading the new game and the values ​​of the variables have not been restored.

Comment: Your use of functions, although technically valid, is very abnormal. Any good introductory material would use syntax like `void saveGame(NewGame G);` to declare it and `saveGame(G);` to call it.

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected it and it looks better, but the problem is still there. The error must be in the use of the ifstream, or in the assignment of the values, I suppose...

Comment: Try opening the output file in append mode (i.e `s.open("save.txt", ios_base::app)`)

Comment: pass `G` as reference when u load

Comment: Thank you very much, @Arne. That was the solution I needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I was going to pass on answering myself and just up-vote the current answer, but I think I need to address something the current answers don't.

The problem is not with `ifstream` at all. If you take a look at the value of `G` inside `loadGame()`, it should be just fine:

```
///LOAD
void loadGame( NewGame G ){

    ifstream l;
    l.open("save.txt");
    l >> G.health;
    l >> G.tipo;
    l.close();

    // My additions: print the value of the variables stored in G
    std::cout << "Health: " << G.health << "\n";
    std::cout << "Tipo: " << G.tipo << "\n";

}
```

This should have the correct value. If it does, then you can be sure that `ifstream` is working properly. That is not your problem.

Your problem is that your parameter is [passed by value](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/72-passing-arguments-by-value/). That means that `loadGame()` works with only a copy of the data passed to it, **not the original**. What that effectively means that `main()` cannot access the data inside `loadGame()`.

You have two options: one is change your function to return a `NewGame` (I'm going to assume from your question that this isn't an option, and have to return `void` for some reason) or, two, [pass by reference](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/):

```
///LOAD
void loadGame( NewGame& G ){ // a single & makes all the difference here

    ifstream l;
    l.open("save.txt");
    l >> G.health;
    l >> G.tipo;
    l.close();
}
```

That will allow you to access the value put in `G` from `main()`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're passing a copy of `G` into `loadgame()` function. Try 
`void loadGame( NewGame& G )` instead.